# SQL Server REPLACE()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

If I have a dynamic query in SQL Server which contains a variable of column names `first_name`, `last_name`, `ref_ID`, `order_ID`, `post_code_ID` how can I replace the all of the values suffixed `_ID` with the same string for example `look_up_value`.

Desired output would be

```
first_name, last_name, look_up_value, look_up_value, look_up_value
```

Currently have `SELECT REPLACE(@Var, '_ID', 'look_up_value')` but that obviously leaves the prefix of the column.

Thanks

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Fields NVARCHAR(MAX)      
DECLARE @Fields2 NVARCHAR(MAX)                         
DECLARE @Return NVARCHAR(MAX) = Char(13)                                        
                              
SET @Fields = ''

SELECT @Fields = @Fields + Column_name + ',' + @Return
FROM Orders.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Recent_Orders'

SELECT @Fields = LEFT(@Fields, (LEN(@Fields) - 2))

SELECT REPLACE(@Fields, '_ID', 'look_up_value')
```

Comment: Show us what the full code is, not a snippet, which is incomplete.

Comment: Where are you getting these column names? Dynamic SQL generation from `sys.columns`?

Comment: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns

Comment: Note that you need to search for `'_ID,'`, not `'_ID'`, to find suffixes only. (`'THE_IDES_OF_MARCH'` shouldn't match.) It would be easier to use a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) expression in the `select` that assembles the list to replace the individual names on-the-fly rather than assembling the string and then trying to fix it. Suggested reading: [`String_Agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: fyi: `String_Agg` was added in SQL Server 2017. One more reason to move to a supported version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
....    
SELECT @Fields = @Fields + case when Column_name like '%[_]ID' then 'look_up_value' else Column_name end + ',' + @Return
....
```